# how to Show Calender(Simmillar to Jquery) In android app

Tags: android, jquery, datepicker

As i am new to android please help me to add calender view in dialog box on button click
I used following but it shows me scrollable day year date pattern calender
but i want to show calender like Jquery calender view which is month wise how can i show please help 
by showing code thnks in advance

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id) {// to create Date dialog      
    switch (id) {   
        case OE_DT_DIALOG_ID:   
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);   

        // set date picker as current date  
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, yy, mm,dd);          
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {  
     // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
         year = selectedYear;   
         month = selectedMonth;     
         day = selectedDay;                              
         // set selected date into btn View 
         lblDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1)       
                .append("-").append(year).append(" "));                  
     }               
 };
```

to show calender like this 
[image]

Comment: you will have to write your own calendar view.

Comment: can you please show me the code snippet ...tht will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Pager View. Make your pager view as horizontal scrollable and get the instance of each month and display that using a fragment. Hope this would give an idea...

Please find the [help](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) here. It is a custom library you've to link with your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you please post some code? Does not have to be specific only enough to put people on the track.